# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, json, spring

I am using this code to return a list of Student as JSON

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/students.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Student> getStudentList(){

        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.setStudentName("Leo");

        Student student2 = new Student();
        student2.setStudentName("Giggix");

        Student student3 = new Student();
        student3.setStudentName("John Cena");

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        students.add(student1);
        students.add(student2);
        students.add(student3);

        return students;

    }
```

Launching Tomcat and going to /students.html I get the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
```

In my pom.xml I have the following dependecies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

I already tried all the solutions posted in similar question, do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have public getter methods for Student class ?

Comment: Here is the class:

public class Student{

  private studentName;

      public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

   public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

}

Answer (score -1):

List list=new ArrayList();

Set the Data type of arraylist also .

Comment: How does this help in fixing the converter problem?